# Inequality on orthonormal basis implies inequality for all elements of Hilbert space?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space. Let $x \in X$. Let $\{y_k\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $X$. I'm trying to prove that 
\begin{align}\label{1}\tag{1}
|\langle x,y_k \rangle| \leq C \quad \forall k
\end{align}
implies 
\begin{align}\label{2}\tag{2}
|\langle x,y \rangle| \leq C' \quad \forall y \in X, \|y\|=1
\end{align}

By density, I know that \eqref{2} is implied by 
\begin{align}\label{3}\tag{3}
|\langle x,y \rangle| \leq C'\|y\| \quad \forall y \in \text{span}(\{y_k\}).
\end{align}

My approach has been to prove \eqref{1} implies \eqref{3}. My attempts have been as follows.

Assume \eqref{1}. Let $y \in \text{span}(\{y_k\})$, so $y=\sum_{k=1}^{n} c_k y_k$. Then 
\begin{align}
|\langle x,y \rangle| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} |c_k| |\langle x,y_k \rangle| \leq C \sum_{k=1}^{n} |c_k|.
\end{align}

Assume \eqref{1}. Let $y \in \text{span}(\{y_k\})$, so $y=\sum_{k=1}^{n} c_k y_k$. Then 
\begin{align}
|\langle x,y \rangle| &= \left|\sum_{k=1}^{n} c_k \langle x,y_k \rangle\right| \leq \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} |c_k|^2 \right)^{1/2} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} |\langle x,y_k \rangle|^2 \right)^{1/2} 
\\
&= \| y \| \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} |\langle x,y_k \rangle|^2 \right)^{1/2}
\leq \| y \| \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} C \right)^{1/2}
\end{align}
where the last equality is by Parseval identity.

Please help me with this proof or explain why the thing I am trying to prove is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are trying to prove is false. Let $x=\sum_{k=1}^N y_k$. Then (1) holds with $C=1$. But the norm of $x$ is $\sqrt{N}$, so $C'$ in (2) must be at least $\sqrt{N}$.

(The best constant $C'$ in (2) is just $\|x\|$.)